# TypeError unsupported operand

Tags: python, csv, typeerror

I got help earlier and got my code to this but unfortunately I get a syntax error and I have spent a while trying to fix it but I can not solve it. Can anyone please point out what I've done wrong.
And I have edited it a little more but now I am having this I'm out of ideas of how to fix it.
error on line 24

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'list'

```
import csv
#turn csv files into a list of lists
with open('train.csv') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
     csv_data = list(reader)

i_list = []
for row in csv_data:
    if (row and int(row[13]) > 0):
        i_list.append(int(row[13]))
H_list = []
for row in csv_data:
    if (row and int(row[13]) <= 0):
        H_list.append(int(row[13]))
except IndexError:
        print("could not find the heart diseases status for the row" + str(row))
Icount = len(i_list)
IPavg = sum(i_list)/len(i_list)
file = open("train.csv")
numline = len(file.readlines())
Hcount = len(H_list)
HPavg = sum(H_list)/len(H_list)


print(numline)
print("Total amount of healthy patients " + str(Icount))
print("Total amount of ill patients " + str(Hcount))
print("Averages of healthy patients " + str(HPavg))
print("Averages of ill patients " + str(IPavg))
```

This is suppose to be the end result I end up with.

```
Please enter a training file name: train.csv
Total Lines Processed: 303
Total Healthy Count: 164
Total Ill Count: 139
Averages of Healthy Patients:
[52.59, 0.56, 2.79, 129.25, 242.64, 0.14, 0.84, 158.38, 0.14, 0.59, 1.41, 0.27, 3.77, 0.00]
Averages of Ill Patients:
[56.63, 0.82, 3.59, 134.57, 251.47, 0.16, 1.17, 139.26, 0.55, 1.57, 1.83, 1.13, 5.80, 2.04]
Seperation Values are:
[54.61, 0.69, 3.19, 131.91, 247.06, 0.15, 1.00, 148.82, 0.34, 1.08, 1.62, 0.70, 4.79, 1.02]
```

A sample of the CSV would be like the values/averages above 13 columns(A-N) 303 lines
Some of them don't have information so are substituted with ?'s.

Comment: which line is the error occuring in ?

Comment: I'm sorry I completely forgot to mention that it was line 24 HPavg = sum(h_list)/len(h_list)

Comment: Now where is `h_list` initialised ?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the format of the CSV please?

Comment: Ok I kinda see what I did I had a capital H on h_list but when I fixed it I get a syntax error instead saying

File "C:/Users/David/Documents/Python/asdf.py", line 24, in <module>
    HPavg = sum(H_list)/(H_list)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'list'

Comment: so now the problem's fixed right ?

Comment: `sum(H_list)/(H_list)` is impossible, and error says very same message - what `6 / [1, 2, 3]` should be equal to?

Comment: what I fail to understand is how u have `sum(H_list)/(H_list) ` in your file, but here you have posted `sum(h_list)/len(h_list)` .. Have u copied this code that u posted here, from elsewhere and not frm your file ?

Comment: there is your problem... You cannot divide a list by an integer. The error explicitly states that? print both the sum(h_list) and the len(h_list) and post the results.

Comment: @KaustavDatta sadly no I thought I had the problem fixed but ended up in the same situation

Comment: @KaustavDatta Sorry no that was just a typo I did when changing the capitalization of it, I fixed the mistake once I noticed what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update the code you're showing. Based on your most recent comment, your current code is:

```
HPavg = sum(H_list)/(H_list)
```

which will raise the TypeError because you're dividing by `H_list`, not `len(H_list)`. It can easily be fixed by reverting it to

```
HPavg = sum(H_list)/len(H_list)
```

Additionally, you're using the lowercase `h_list` in `h_list.append(int(row[13]))`, which needs to be changed to `H_list`.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion I was about to edit the problem to show the changes I did. It is correct now and again I apologize for the mix up I deleted 2 far and didn't realize when I was changing it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I reanalyzed what I was doing and realized where I went wrong. There was a piece of the code that I did not get rid of when I was getting rid of another part of the code that was not needed. Thanks everyone for the help the code now looks like this.

```
import csv
#turn csv files into a list of lists
with open('train.csv') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
     csv_data = list(reader)

i_list = []
for row in csv_data:
    if (row and int(row[13]) > 0):
        i_list.append(int(row[13]))
H_list = []
for row in csv_data:
    if (row and int(row[13]) <= 0):
        H_list.append(int(row[13]))

Icount = len(i_list)
IPavg = sum(i_list)/len(i_list)
Hcount = len(H_list)
HPavg = sum(H_list)/len(H_list)
file = open("train.csv")
numline = len(file.readlines())

print(numline)
print("Total amount of healthy patients " + str(Icount))
print("Total amount of ill patients " + str(Hcount))
print("Averages of healthy patients " + str(HPavg))
print("Averages of ill patients " + str(IPavg))
```

Again Thanks everyone and sorry for the confusion I really appreciate your help and am grateful to you.